# In postgres with a non-unique column storing a wide range of values, is it possible to index it and gain in performance?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I receive large anounts of data on a growing number of users who attempt a physical feat but then lose interest and leave. Each user is given a unique id. Each attempt is given a unique id. Data flows to me in the form of a table relating the users to attempts (rel_user_attempts). Note the attempts arrived in batches but not always chronologically.

```
rel_user_attempts
-----------------
id (pk)   archived    userid      attemptid (unique)
1         false       152         4001
2         false       152         4002
3         false       152         4003
4         false       19          4004
5         false       19          4005
6         false       19          4006
7         false       2409        3301
8         true        2409        3302
9         false       2409        3303
... etc
```

The most common search my analytics team will perform is by user (example user 19)

`SELECT * FROM rel_user_attempts WHERE userid=19 AND archived=false;`

In postgres with a non-unique column (userid) storing a wide range of values is it possible to index it and gain in performance?

Comment: This might be better asked in sister site http://DBA.StackExchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit of using any index, or whether Postgres might even choose to use a particular index, depends on several things, among them including the *cardinality* of the underlying data.  Indices help the most when used on columns which tend to have values which are either unique or relatively unique.  You may find the following index to be helpful here:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON rel_user_attempts (userid, archived);
```

The cardinality on the `userid` column appears, at least from your sample data, to be not high, but at least somewhat high.  Given that `archived` is a boolean column, assuming that true/false values occur with equal probability, the cardinality on this column would be low.  But, we can still include it in the above index to completely cover the `WHERE` clause of your query.  Consider adding the above index and then checking the execution plan.

Comment: archived boolean is actually for cheating or an invalidated attempt due to weather or human inaccuracies from the recording staff or other unforeseen influences. Ideally the archived true should be low but reality might be 30%